# How to extract a specific list of files from a folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, explorer

I have a folder of around 3,000 music files of all the same type (.flac).

I made an excel (and .txt) list of around 1,000 files in that folder that I want to move to a different folder.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to manually move each file by referencing the list?

Thank you!

Comment: How is this related to programming? Have you tried running a simple `move` from the command line?

Comment: Oh sorry thought this was the right place to post this, is there a more appropriate stackexchange forum to post at?

Comment: The correct site would be `superuser`. Moving files can be done with `move *.flac newPath`. With 1000 files though, you may want to look into [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and use options like eg `/minage:10` to move files older than 10 days

Comment: Ah okay, and yeah the files are just random files from the list, so there's no file attributes that you could specify them with, it would have to pull from the txt list I made

Comment: there are shell commands that work with file lists too. There's no reason to write a program for that. Even if you want to, a shell script can already do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a backup of everything!
Yes this is indeed possible, I wrote a little python script for you:

```
import os

f = open("whichtomove.txt", "r")

filelist = f.read().split("\n")

for x in range(0, len(filelist)):
    os.rename(("fromhere/" + str(filelist[x])),("tohere/" + str(filelist[x])))
```

You just have to change the folder paths and I assumed the list is in this format:

```
file1.flac
tihs.flac
```

If the format in your format is another you just have to change the split operator, e.g. to ";" if you split the list entries with ';'

Comment: Why write a script to do what shell commands like `move` and `copy` do? Or Powershell's commands?

Comment: Because I'm not really into powershell commands and this was short enough. If you know the commands for this, I'm sure it's appreciated too.

Comment: Thanks, trying this now, I'll let you know if I have any struggles!

Comment: Okay I'm having some issue:
https://i.imgur.com/mgWJY7H.jpg
Am I doing something simple/stupid lol? It's been a while since I've used Python to be honest, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/WOkAGxY.jpg

Comment: Oh yeah, you missed the "/" at the end of the location.

Comment: Yep, just tried that and it worked lol. Thank you a bunch!!!